# How to filter a listView without notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, android-listview

While working on my first app I'd like to give the user the ability to search the entries in a ListView (it's in the UI-Thread).
For that, I added the SearchView into the Action Bar.

```
listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

In an AsyncTask I set the Adapter to the listView:

```
protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {
ListAdapter listadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, nameList);
listview1.setAdapter(listadapter);
}
```

Now the SearchView:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);    
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
return true;
[...]
}
```

Also I added these functions:

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    ListView listview1= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    listview1.setFilterText(newText);
    //mFilter.filter(newText);
    return false;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    ListView listview1= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    listview1.setFilterText(query);
}
```

Now the filtering *is* working fine, but this overlay with the searched char sequence  is hiding the filtered data -> it doesn't look well.

As I read everywhere, there's no simple possibility to turn this overlay off.
So I changed my code a bit:

```
onPostExecute(blaaaaa) { [...]
     //Filter mFilter= = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, nameList).getFilter();
```

and the two functions:

```
 //mFilter.filter(the_entered_text);
 ((ArrayAdapter<String>)listAdapter).getFilter().filter(query);
 ((ArrayAdapter<String>)listAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**My question is now, how can I let the listView get updated?**
That "listview1.notifyDataSetChanged()" is no option for me, because it isn't available for my ListAdapter.

EDIT: cast the adapter, as in an answer postet, now it works, but it filters so: entered text= "ka" -> all entries, which start with "ka" are displayed, not the ones which contain "ka".

Comment: Sorry that you're frustrated but there's no need to swear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listview1.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`

Simples

Comment: Thanks, but the function "getListAdapter" is not available for my listView, dont know why, but it isn't in the suggestion when entering "listView1.".

Comment: The MainActivity extends Activity and implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

Comment: What class is your ListView?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but the ListView is in the MainActivity.

Comment: Also then, when I call "listview.getAdapter()." there are only "notify()" and "notifyall()" suggested.

Comment: Is listview1 a View or a ListView? It should be a ListView (cast it from findViewById())

Comment: Yes, it is casted from findViewById(R.id.mylist) like ListView listview1 = findViewById(R.id.mylist);

Comment: You need to cast the Adapter to whatever you are using

Comment: how do I do that? My adapter is of <ArrayList<String>>

Comment: `((ArrayAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Well, that works now, but now just the entries are displayed, which start with the entered query string, not the ones too which contain the query string (at x-position).

Comment: I'm not sure, but they are showing up. I'm not sure what the filter text does

Comment: Actually, the filter shows the entries beginning with the query string AND it also shows the entries which contain the query string (e.g.: query= "ha" -> shows the entries "Hazel" and "My Hazelnut". So for my application it is okay.